# MacOS render images from PDFs (no third party render lib)

Tags: macos, pdf, applescript, rendering, automator

I'm trying to render 50k images using a Mac Mini. I don't know much about the system, but I need to use the built-in renderer like the Preview.app.

I currently tested to set up an Automator script that could take files selected in the Finder window, render images, and move them to another directory.

But running that script with 50k single-page PDFs does not work. Instead, it seems to use the memory to store the PDFs or something like that.

I have never written any AppleScript, Swift, or similar code, but I'm well versed in Bash and Java, so if I could do this from the command line, then it would be ideal, but if someone has a suggestion on an AppleScript that could solve this issue I'm all ears.

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: To save a pdf as a png using applescript, a simple way would be to first set up a reference to a file with the desired name: `set pdk to ((path to desktop) as text) & "outs.png"` and then have Preview save into that reference: `tell application "Preview" to save document 1 as "public.png" in file pdk`. You could build a file-feeding mechanism in either bash or applescript as well as one to prepare the name. These applescript commands can also be called from bash… try `man osascript` for details.

Comment: Also, you could stay entirely within the shell with Poppler-utils, specifically the pdftocairo command, which can convert single pages to various image formats.

Comment: The question was for  rendering PDFs using Preview. But I have already dealt with the issue of rasterizing PDF files, and if the OP is interested, I already have a ready-made script much faster than Preview, and without using a third-party software.

Comment: Hi @RobertKniazidis

I could be interested in another solution as well. The important thing is to use the built-in library for rendering as we want to validate the rendering Safari, MacOS or iOS does for PDFs.

Comment: This is completely incomprehensible to me. Perhaps because I do not speak English very well. I think you want to change your original question. But then it should be set in a separate topic. Alternatively, use @Mockman's answer if you find my script too clever. His answer with Preview should work, only more slowly. Wish you all the best with 50,000 images and the Preview.app.

Comment: Top hit on Google for “pdf to png mac command line”: [How to convert PDF to PNG from the command line on a Mac](https://ademcan.net/blog/2013/04/10/how-to-convert-pdf-to-png-from-the-command-line-on-a-mac/). See also: [Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service](https://sopython.com/wiki/Useful_Comments#code-service).

Comment: Hi @foo

Great, thank you for the answer. That was pretty much what I was looking for. I'm sad to say that I searched a lot and didn't see anyone mentioning the actual engine used for sips so I thought it was a third party system.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- 1) Create --> **Quick Action** (that is, service)
-- 2) Set: **Workflow receives current PDFs in Finder.app**
-- 3) Add action **Run AppleScript** with following content.
-- 4) Save this service with name like "Render images from single_page PDFs".

use scripting additions
use framework "Foundation"
use framework "AppKit"
use framework "Quartz"
use framework "QuartzCore"

on run {input, parameters}
    set destinationFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Please, choose Destination Folder")
    set destFolderPosixPath to POSIX path of destinationFolder
    repeat with aPDF in (get input)
        (my rasterPDF:aPDF savingToFolder:destFolderPosixPath)
    end repeat
    return input
end run

on rasterPDF:aPDF savingToFolder:destFolderPosixPath
    set aURL to (|NSURL|'s fileURLWithPath:(POSIX path of aPDF))
    set fileName to aURL's lastPathComponent()
    set baseName to fileName's stringByDeletingPathExtension()
    set aPDFdoc to PDFDocument's alloc()'s initWithURL:aURL
    set doc to (NSImage's alloc()'s initWithData:((aPDFdoc's pageAtIndex:0)'s dataRepresentation()))
    if doc = missing value then error "Error in getting image from PDF"
    set theData to doc's TIFFRepresentation()
    set aNSBitmapImageRep to (NSBitmapImageRep's imageRepsWithData:theData)'s objectAtIndex:0
    set outNSURL to |NSURL|'s fileURLWithPath:(destFolderPosixPath & baseName & ".png")
    set outputPNGData to aNSBitmapImageRep's representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType |properties|:{NSImageCompressionFactor:0.8, NSImageProgressive:false}
    outputPNGData's writeToURL:outNSURL atomically:true
end rasterPDF:savingToFolder:
```

NOTE: 1) the script renders image from first page of multiple_page PDFs as well. 2) with using repeat loop and with changing pageAtIndex property, someone can adapt my script to render images from all PDF pages.